# Generate coordinates for cube

Tags: c#, algorithm

Hi i just write function in C# that generate coordinate for cube but the problem i want just

generate the coordinate of cube sides not in the depth !!!

```
static class Util
{
    public static List<string> GenerateCubeCoord(double bc,int nt,double stp)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        double CoorBase = bc;
        int n = nt;
        double step = stp;
        int id = 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
                {
                    list.Add(string.Format("GRID {0} {1}.0 {2}.0 {3}.0 \n",
                        id, step * x + CoorBase, step * y + CoorBase, step * z + CoorBase));

                    id++;
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

}

I wat to generate all this coordinate not the corner coordinates of cube , in the image one

side of may cube

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "i want just generate the coordinate of cube sides not in the depth".

U mean for a 3x3x3 cube the program should print only the coordinates of the 8 corner points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing your code too much  (assuming you meant *all corner points*, it's a little unclear):

```
for (int x = 0; x <= n; x += n)
    for (int y = 0; y <= n; y += n)
        for (int z = 0; z <= n; z += n)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", x, y, z);
```

A little cleaner using LINQ:

```
int n = 6;
var coords = from x in new[] { 0, n }
             from y in new[] { 0, n }
             from z in new[] { 0, n }
             select new { x, y, z };

foreach(var coord in coords)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", coord.x, coord.y, coord.z);
```

Edit after updated question:

If you just want the coordinates of the sides, the allowed values for one coordinate (x,y or z) are either 0 or n-1:

```
var coords = from x in new[] { 0, n-1 }
             from y in Enumerable.Range(0, n) 
             from z in Enumerable.Range(0, n) 
             select new { x, y, z };
```

Rinse and repeat for the other two and you have the set of coordinates for all 6 sides.

**Edit:**

With above solution there are overlaps between the different sides (the edge points), so you'd have to use the union of all 3 collections. A better solution is to query for all coordinates in one go:

```
var coords = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, n)
             from y in Enumerable.Range(0, n) 
             from z in Enumerable.Range(0, n) 
             where ( x == 0 || x==n-1 || y == 0 || y== n-1 || z == 0 || z== n-1)
             select new { x, y, z };
```